# How to use get_loc to get the position of a specific label?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas Dataframe representing a Matrix:

```
product            63727    63729    63741    63750    ...  1180572  1181075  1181077  1182263
username                                               ...                                    
ali8                   0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0  ...      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0
micheal54              0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0  ...      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0
aaron176               0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0  ...      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0
rose_2                 0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0  ...      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0
sara_pv2               0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0  ...      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0
```

I'm trying to perform KNN over it to get the most similar users to the one I'm indicating, so I'm trying to use:

```
query_index = order_products.index.get_loc('rose_2')
```

to **get the index position** of the username in question I want to get similar users for.
But that raises the next **error**:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Which I don't know how to fix.

Comment: What is reason use `query` ? What is expected output for `query` ? Why not use only `query_index = order_products.index.get_loc('rose_2')` ?

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake, I think I've fixed it, that's exactly what I'm trying to use: `query_index = order_products.index.get_loc('rose_2')` but I'm getting the error I showed above.

Comment: hmmm, so `query_index = order_products.index.get_loc('rose_2')` returned error `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable` ? I cannot simulate this error.

Comment: How can I help?

Comment: hmmm, is possible answer for last comment?

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a small example that might help you:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(data={"63727":["0.0","0.0","0.0","0.0"]},index=['product','username','ali8','micheal54'])
display(df)
np.where(df.index.values=='ali8')[0][0]
```

You can get the integer for the index position with the specified name this way.
I hope it is helpful.